# Use JPA console with Springboot in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use ItelliJ Idea JPA Console

[image]

In a normal Springboot Application

If I try to run a query

[image]

I hibernate complains saing that hibernate.dialect is missing.
I put an entry in my application.property file

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

but nothing happened.
Where can I configure properly IntelliJ Idea?